# Blackberry - how to add fields to listfield?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls, listfield

I am using ListField but encouter a problem. How can i view it as i wish (not one by one)?
For instance, there is item1, item2, item3. Can i jump from item1 to item3 directly, ignoring item2 ?

In another way, how to insert a text field (a labelfield, for example) into the ListField items?

like this:

item1
a textlabel
item2
item3
......

let me describe it in another way:

that is, how to insert a text field(a labelfield,for example) into the ListField items. like this: item1
a textlabel item2 item3 ..

---

let me describe it in another way:

that is, how to insert a text field(a labelfield,for example) into the ListField items.
like this:  item1
 a textlabel
item2
item3
......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListField is more like presentation/select control. You can implement custom layout/draw logic inside ListField, on example like in  [rtm4bb](http://code.google.com/p/rtm4bb/):
[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://rtm4bb.googlecode.com/files/task_list_5-01.png))</sub>

**But I dont know the way to add different controls into ListField. In such case I would recommend to use VerticalFieldManager with added fields.**

Comment: hi.i have to create listfield like above image.can u provide any usefull links to create like that.a list row with three textfields.iam new to blackberry.so can u help..

Comment: i created the  listfield by refering the above link.iam getting the problem that is not able to view the fields in listfield.i raised the question in stackoverflow there i kept my code which i have tried.can u look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731554/in-listfield-not-able-to-view-the-fields-in-blackberry and can u help where iam doing the mistake.